# The simplest way to check if HTTP request has no parameters in flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, flask-restful

I am using `flask_restful` to build an api server that abstracts a database. I would like to support lots of HTTP request parameters and I am wondering if there is a simple way to check whether no parameters were passed other than write a mile long if statement. Yes, I could wrap the if statement into a function, but I hope there is a default simpler way that I am unaware of.

```py
# Query args
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("arg1", type=str, required=False)
parser.add_argument("arg2", type=str, required=False)
parser.add_argument("argn", type=str, required=False)

# API Resource
class SomeResource(Resource):
   
  def get(self):
   
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # A mile long if statement. 
    if not args['arg1'] and not args['arg2'] and not args['argn']:

       result = Unicorndb.query.all()

       return UnicornSchema(many=True).dump(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 functions are there. `all` and `any`

if you have a list like this `list = [True, False, True]` and if you're applying the above 2 functions for this list, you will get something like this,

```
>>> l = [True, False, True]
>>> all(l)
False
>>> any(l)
True
>>>
>>> l = [True, True]
>>> all(l)
True
>>> any(l)
True
>>>
>>> l = [False, False]
>>> all(l)
False
>>> any(l)
False
```

From this, you can clearly see that `all` function will return True if all values are True, and `any` function will return if at least one value is true.

This is not only for True and False but applicable to all.
It will convert into a bool. for ex: `bool(1) = True`

1. String will consider as True if it has some characters
2. Empty string will be considered as False
3. List/Tuple?dictionary will be considered as True if it has some value.
4. 0 will be Flase, other numbers will be taken as True
5. None is considered as False

With this understanding, we can do something like this in your case.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class SomeResource(Resource):

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('rate', type=int, help='Rate cannot be converted')
        parser.add_argument('name')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args.values())
        print(any(args.values()))
```

if you not passing any arguments and if you print args you will get `{'rate': None, 'name': None}` Both values are None. `bool(None)` will be False.

So take the args.values() and pass this into `all` function. If all the arguments are passed, then you will get `True` value. or you can call `any` function. This will return `True` at least one value is passed.

In a single word:

```
if not args['arg1'] and not args['arg2'] and not args['argn']:
# instead of this, use the below line

if not any(args.values()):
```

Comment: Did you mean `args.values()`?